# 'this' argument to member function 'attacked' has type 'const Pokemon', but function is not marked const

Tags: c++

I'm trying to call a function on a polymorphic item. But I get the following error message at compile time:

```
'this' argument to member function 'attacked' has type 'const Pokemon', but function is not marked const
```

The question is, I don't even use `const` in my code.

Here's my code.

```
class Pokemon
{
public:
    
    QString name;
    QString attackName;
    int id;
    int grade;
    bool evolved;
    bool skillEvolved;
    int exp;
    int atta;
    int defense;
    int hp;
    int interval;

    
    Pokemon();
    virtual void upgrade();
    virtual int attack() ;
    void attacked(int value) ;
};
```

```
void Pokemon::attacked(int value) 
{
    if(evolved == true)
    {
        hp -= value * 0.8;
    }
    else
    {
        hp -= value;
    }
}
```

I define the function `attacked` in another item as belows:

```
void FightWidget::fight(Pokemon &mPokemon, Pokemon &sPokemon)
{
    bool flag = false;
    while(flag == false)
    {
       
        QTimer::singleShot(200, this, [=]{
            
            sPokemon.attacked();   //Here the bug is.
            
        });
    }

}
```

I am really confused, thanks for your help!

Comment: `[=]` you capture `sPokemon` by const copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda has a default capture `[=]`, and so captured variables are `const`. If you want to call a non-const function on a captured variable in the lambda, you can capture it by reference with `[&]` like this:

```
QTimer::singleShot(200, this, [&] {    
      sPokemon.attacked(42);   // ok    
});
```

Note that I used a dummy argument, since `attacked` takes an `int` parameter.

Alternatively, you can keep the default capture, but make the lambda `mutable` like this:

```
QTimer::singleShot(200, this, [=] () mutable { 
     sPokemon.attacked(42);   // ok
});
```